# Python: Writing to file from HTML form variables, 500 internal server error?

Tags: python, html, forms

I'm getting a 500 internal server error but I'm not sure why? I don't know if it's an issue or syntax or what but thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

z = open("survey.ssv", "r")
f = open("results.ssv", "a+")
lines = z.readlines()
i = 0
for line in lines:
    if i == 0:
    else:
        if form.getvalue("demFeels%d") == stronglyAgree % i
            f.write("1 ")
        if form.getvalue("demFeels%d") == agree % i
            f.write("2 ")
        if form.getvalue("demFeels%d") == disagree % i
            f.write("3 ")
        if form.getvalue("demFeels%d") == stronglyDisagree % i
            f.write("4 ")
    i = i + 1    
f.close()
z.close()
```

Comment: CGI..... really? Do you have to?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code, I can see that it is due to a `SyntaxError`, more specifically in your `if` statements.

Change:

```
if form.getvalue("demFeels%d") == stronglyAgree % i
```

To:

```
if form.getvalue("demFeels%d") == stronglyAgree % i:
                                                   ^
```

Do that for all of the `if` statements within that `else` block and then that part of the issue is resolved.

Furthermore, you have nothing within this conditional statement:

```
if i == 0:  # Something needs to go here.
```

At the moment it results in an `Expected an indented block`.

Comment: The if i == 0 is meant to do nothing. I want it to skip the i=0 case and do the i>=1 cases

Comment: @user3251142 In which case, instead of `if: else:`, put your code in the `else:` within `if i > 0:` and get rid of the original `if`. Or, just add `pass` to the `if` statement you have in place at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It is a syntax error. You are missing the colon after several of your 'if' statements.

To debug this in the future, you can run your code with the Python interpreter. The CGI stuff won't work, but if you get a syntax error the interpreter will show you where.

Alternately, you could consult your webserver error logs to see what error was thrown.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the missing colons that others have pointed out, you also have a problem with your string formatting. The `%` has to come immediately after the string that is to be formatted - not at the end of the line. So it should be:

```
if form.getvalue("demFeels%d" % i) == stronglyAgree:
```

and so on.